# Systemmodeler owner and other Mathematica owner

Tags: system-modeler

My daughter has Mathematica. I want to buy SystemModeler Wolfram. Can i use my daughter’s mathematica with my SystemModeler?

Comment: Best to just call Wolfram and ask.

Answer (score 1):

I have a commercial class license for Mathematica and my download included System Modeler, so I know it works with Mathematica. There are built-in Mathematica functions to support interacting with System Modeler; e.g., [`SystemModelExamples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemModelExamples.html), which provides a nice user interface that let's the Mathematica user play a number of pre-built models.

[image: interface]